# Insert two arrays into one mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, foreach

I'm new at PHP and am stuck trying to insert data from two arrays into one mysql table.

The Table stores following fields: `date`, `case_id`, `statusid`

`case_id` would be the same for all records inserted in one statement and the value comes from a session variable.

the `date` array and `status_id` array are both being posted from a form; I know both arrays are posting fine because I've used a for each loop to insert both arrays to the table individually.

Any help will be much appreciated. I've left the foreach condition empty for suggestions.

```
$caseid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['caseid']);
$status = $_POST['statuses'];
$date = $_POST['dates'];

foreach() {
    $sql = " INSERT INTO casestatus (date, case_id, statusid) VALUE 
                                    ('$date', '$caseid', '$statusid') ";

    if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        $error = 'Error assigning selected statuses to case.';
        include 'error.php';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
// Avoid SQL Injections.
$caseid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['caseid']); 
$statuses = $_POST['statuses']; 
$dates = $_POST['dates'];

$i = 0;
foreach($statuses as $status)
{
  if($i < sizeof($dates))
  {
    $statusid = mysqli_real_escape_string($status);
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dates[$i]); 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO casestatus (date, case_id, statusid) VALUES ('$date', '$caseid', '$statusid')";
    $i++:
  }
  // etc...
}
```

Don't forget to replace `VALUE` with `VALUES` in your INSERT statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I've replaced with the code you provided and I get the following error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: in the updated solution do I remove the for each loop? or do i just replace existing lines with the new ones

Comment: Remove the foreach loop since values from the $_POST calls are single values.

Comment: The values from $_POST calls are arrays, when i run the modeified code it throws this error for each $_POST Variable....  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: I changed it to ; and it doesn't throw syntax but still same error mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: Did you remove the surrounding mysql_real_escape_string() function calls? In that case you would not get this error. Try remove them temporary and add them to the strings later on.

Comment: sorry, i realised before you replied... I've removed mysql_real_escape_string() and it's now adding records to the database fine, only one problem... see comment below...

Comment: I think we need to switch this around so we are incrementing through statuses instead of dates in the for each loop because we only want to add each status that is selected in the form.

Comment: how can i add the mysqli_real_escape_string() back in without throwing an error??

Comment: You have to surround all calls to $statuses[$i] and $date with a mysql_real_escape_string() call. These are single values and will work.

Comment: my joy was premature... when I've switched the dates and statuses around in the foreach loop, i've introduced another problem - If the first statuses in our form is not checked the dates don't match up

Comment: I updated the solution to handle the problem with to many dates.

Comment: dates still dont match up... we have chceckboxes for statuses [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and dates for each. if a checkbox is not selected the date is blank. code provided is successfully adding only the checked statuses but then it loops through dates in order of appearance... so if status 1 3 and 6 are checked it will insert correct date for 1, no date for 3 and date that was meant for 3 into 6

Comment: i think we need it to recognise if a date is blank or null and exclude it from looped dates

Comment: Since they are stored together you can either insert default values or like in the above solution, just omit them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on all of your values, unless you like to be pwnd.

```
$caseid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['caseid']); 
$statuses = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['statuses']); 
$dates = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['dates']);
```

Comment: yes of course, always do just forgot to write it in the post above